# FIlter Results of Api Call

Tags: javascript, json, api

my .json is located at https://aaronlilly.github.io/PokeApp/api/v2/pokemon/FakeLego2.json

```
{
    "results": 
[
  {
     "ID": 2924,
    "SetNumber": 7942,
    "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4586972.pdf",
    "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4586972.png",
    "Description": "Off Road Fire Rescue",
    "DashedNumber": "7942-1",
    "Preselect": "fire"
  },
  {
  "ID": 4470,
  "SetNumber": 7942,
  "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4656089.pdf",
  "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4656089.png",
  "Description": "Police Boat",
  "DashedNumber": "7287-1 ",
  "Preselect": "police"
  }
],"next":"1
```

my script is

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search-now').click(function () {
            $.ajax
            ({
                method: "GET",
                     url: "https://aaronlilly.github.io/PokeApp/api/v2/pokemon/FakeLego2.json"
            }).done(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                     $("#legoList").append(data.results[i].Preselect + "<br>");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```

I wanted my example to be simple, so I created this .json file, but in the end I would like to have the user type a search into a field and return items which match a description that contains the word in the search field.

**update**

I found out how to filter, but I am still struggling on how to filter dynamically. Below I create an array named obj and set it up just like my json, then I have a filter to write to console for the item with id 2924.

```
 var obj = {
  'results': [{
        "ID": 2924,
  "SetNumber": 7942,
  "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4586972.pdf",
  "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4586972.png",
  "Description": "Off Road Fire Rescue",
  "DashedNumber": "7942-1",
  "Preselect": "fire"
    }, {
          "ID": 4470,
  "SetNumber": 7942,
  "URL": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4656089.pdf",
  "Images": "https://www.lego.com/biassets/biimg/4656089.png",
  "Description": "Police Boat",
  "DashedNumber": "7287-1 ",
  "Preselect": "police"
    },

]
};

var newArray = obj.results.filter(function (el) {
return el.ID ==  2924 &&
     el.SetNumber &&
     el.URL &&
     el.Images &&
     el.Description &&
     el.DashedNumber &&
     el.Preselect ; 
  });
  console.log(newArray);
```

I now want to do this dynamically.

I have added a field to my page

```
 <input type="text" id="prodId" size="37" placeholder="Search Field"     style="margin-left: 50px;margin-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 4px;">
```

so I try to move the prodId value into my new array, but this doesn't quite work.

```
var newArray = obj.results.filter(function (el) {
return el.ID ==  $('#prodId').val() &&
     el.SetNumber &&
     el.URL &&
     el.Images &&
     el.Description &&
     el.DashedNumber &&
     el.Preselect ; 
});
console.log(newArray);
```

hopefully you see that I am trying :) any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I found out how to filter, but I am still struggling on how to filter dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#prodId').click(function () {
var newArray = obj.results.filter(function (el) {
return el.ID ==  $('#prodId').val() &&
 el.SetNumber &&
 el.URL &&
 el.Images &&
 el.Description &&
 el.DashedNumber &&
 el.Preselect ; 
 });
console.log(newArray);
```

this however will show exact matches to (ID ie. 2924, or 4470)